# GridBagConstraints not right aligning with GridBagConstraints.EAST

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

I want my multiline label to be right aligned... not sure why this is sooo difficult.  I have tried using weightx and added a blank jlabel and giving it weight of 1.0.  I cant get this to work.  The idea is the one person is all left aligned and the other person is right aligned. (kinda like a texting app).  Can anyone suggest something?  I keep trying to find similar posts, but there are so many threads with GBLayout issues!

```
JLabel rightLblName = new JLabel(npcName);
GridBagConstraints gbc_rightLblName = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_rightLblName.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
gbc_rightLblName.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
gbc_rightLblName.gridx = 5;
gbc_rightLblName.gridy = 2;
DialogueJInternalFrame.dialoguePanel.add(rightLblName, gbc_rightLblName);

JLabel rightLblImage = new JLabel("");
rightLblImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(SpriteSheetCutter.makeColorTransparent((BufferedImage) SpriteStore.get().getSprite(npcFilename).getImage())));
rightLblImage.setBorder(DialogueJInternalFrame.raisedetched);
GridBagConstraints gbc_rightLblImage = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_rightLblImage.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
gbc_rightLblImage.gridx = 6;
gbc_rightLblImage.gridy = 2;
DialogueJInternalFrame.dialoguePanel.add(rightLblImage, gbc_rightLblImage);

JMultilineLabel rightLblChatText = new JMultilineLabel(valuesSplit[1]);
GridBagConstraints gbc_rightLblChatText = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_rightLblChatText.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc_rightLblChatText.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
gbc_rightLblChatText.gridwidth = 7;
gbc_rightLblChatText.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
gbc_rightLblChatText.gridx = 0;
gbc_rightLblChatText.gridy = 3;
DialogueJInternalFrame.dialoguePanel.add(rightLblChatText, gbc_rightLblChatText);
```

[image]

The bottom text chunk should be hugging the right side.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I've never heard of a JMultilineLabel before.  You could try rightLblChatText.setHorizontal or rightLblChatText.selAlignmentX.

Comment: Its a custom Label implementation... I think GBL wont work for me because I have tried that

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem in next line `gbc_rightLblChatText.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;`

with that you loose effect of `anchor`, set `fill` property  to `gbc_rightLblChatText.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;`, it will help you.

EDIT: seems your label extends `JLabel` in this case use next code, it align your component to the `EAST`:

```
gbc_rightLblChatText.weightx = 1;
gbc_rightLblChatText.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
jLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
```

`jLabel` is your label.

Comment: The problem is that I want it filled and aligned right.  I will have to come up with another solution here(maybe adding JPanels and different layouts)